# Приложение читающее библиотеку .kle (html файл из архива)

Tags: python

Задача:
Создать ПРОСТОЕ приложение на tkinter, читающее библиотеку .kle (КОМПАС 3D)
(а точнее html файл из него), выводящее полный список содержимого с возможностью выбора строк.
(извлечение одного файла из архива, чтение его тегов и разбиение все по столбцам и строкам в приложении, при выборе нажатие замены или добавления файла из библиотеки)

Вопрос:
можете ли посоветовать какие-либо примеры со ссылками? (распаковка одного файла из архива, чтение тегов, визуализация в виде таблицы с изменяемыми размерами столбцов и строк)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Стандартный zipfile (или библиотека для нужного формата архива) + lxml (для html) + treeview из tkinter. Все.

Comment: insolor, спасибо, а ссылочками на примеры можете поделиться?

Comment: Могу, но для каждой ссылки мне нужно будет пойти в поисковик, и по названию найти примеры. Я думаю, вы вполне с этим справитесь самостоятельно.

Comment: а как быть с изображением файла?

Comment: Если вы про таблицу, то treeview из tkinter с этим справится (он не только для отображения в виде дерева, но и для таблиц)

Comment: я про нижнее окно 'изображение модели, сборки, эскиза'...

Comment: А это уже нужно смотреть что за формат, и как из него что извлечь.

Comment: есть что почитать по данному вопросу?

Comment: Открывается архивом, имеет файл Preview и папку images, в которой cghqks.tb, lnqpyr.TechnicalDemand и qpxppe.sl.   Ни один из документов не открывается как .jpg.

Comment: При открытии файлов с блокнота: Preview - KF', cghqks.tb - PK, lnqpyr.TechnicalDemand - KF, qpxppe.sl - KF.